# How to graph $x^2+y^2=4$ on a TI-$84$?

Tags: graphing-functions, calculator

I have a TI-$84$ and need to graph an equation that does not begin with $Y=$.

How would I do this?

Comment: How about graphing $y_1=\sqrt{4-x^2}$ and $y_2=-\sqrt{4-x^2}$ instead? In case of the TI-$89$ there was the possibility of parameterization, i.e. $(x,y)=(\cos t,\sin t)$ (with $0\leqslant t<2\pi$) for a circle with radius $r=1$ for instance.

Comment: I added I an example to my answer! You should check it out ;)

Comment: I’m sad this question was closed as off-topic. Why else would we have calculator and graphing-functions tags?

Comment: Thank you all! I'm sorry this post got closed, I don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parametrise: get the equation in terms of $t$. Or you could convert to polar coordinates: use the form $r$ as a function of $\theta$.

However, in general, this can be complicated. Instead you need to solve for $Y$ and graph all solutions simultaneously, remembering that you can *only* graph $Y$ as a *function* of $X$.

$$\begin{align}
X^2 + Y^2 &= 4 \\
Y^2 &= 4 - X^2 \\
Y &= \pm \sqrt{4-X^2}
\end{align}$$

Hence graph $$Y_1 =+\sqrt{4-X^2} \\ Y_2 = -\sqrt{4-X^2}$$

(Obviously omit the $+$ on the calculator.)

This method is not always possible. I recommend using Desmos.com—go check it out. [Here’s](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gpdbjaytqn) how simple it is!